# Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.sample.loadermanegersample.MainActivity.access$super

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

I just using really simple loadermaneger sample and it's not working and keep showing this error message in logcat

```
Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method 
com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources
06-20 17:43:05.627 28038-28038/com.ahoosoft.loadermanegersample W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1789 (Landroid/util/ArrayMap;) in Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/MonkeyPatcher;
06-20 17:43:05.627 28038-28038/com.ahoosoft.loadermanegersample E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.pruneResourceCache
06-20 17:43:05.647 28038-28038/com.ahoosoft.loadermanegersample W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve const-class 1789 (Landroid/util/ArrayMap;) in Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/MonkeyPatcher;
06-20 17:43:05.687 28038-28038/com.ahoosoft.loadermanegersample W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 442: Landroid/content/Context;.getSystemService (Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
06-20 17:43:05.687 28038-28038/com.ahoosoft.loadermanegersample W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 210: Landroid/app/Activity;.startActivity (Landroid/content/Intent;Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
06-20 17:43:05.697 28038-28038/com.ahoosoft.loadermanegersample W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 231: Landroid/app/Activity;.stopLockTask ()V
06-20 17:43:05.697 28038-28038/com.ahoosoft.loadermanegersample E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.ahoosoft.loadermanegersample.MainActivity.access$super
```

and loader never called
this is my code
mainactivity class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main,BlankFragment.newInstance(),"dd");
}
```

my fragment

```
 public class BlankFragment extends Fragment implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<List<ArrayList<Event>>>>{
String tag="BlankFragment ";

public BlankFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static BlankFragment newInstance() {
    BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
    return fragment;
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
}

@Override
public Loader<List<List<ArrayList<Event>>>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    Log.d(tag,"onCreateLoader");
    return new EventLoader(getContext());
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<List<ArrayList<Event>>>> loader, List<List<ArrayList<Event>>> data) {
    Log.d(tag,"onLoadFinished");
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<List<ArrayList<Event>>>> loader) {
    Log.d(tag,"onLoaderReset");
}
}
```

and my event loader class

```
public class EventLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader< List<List<ArrayList<Event>>>> {
String tag="EventLoader ";
public EventLoader(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

@Override
public List<List<ArrayList<Event>>> loadInBackground() {

    List<List<ArrayList<Event>>> monthEvents =new ArrayList<>();


    Log.d(tag,"monthEvents.size="+monthEvents.size());

    return monthEvents;
}
}
```

as you can see nothing really complex but i do not know why it is not working.
can anyone help me about this?

Comment: are you using ArrayMap somewhere in your code?

Comment: thanks for your attention. and no.

Comment: Which SDK version are you using?